# Late 90's/early 00's movie about a revolutionary leader and an agent hunting him

Tags: identify-this-movie

I do not have actors' names for the movie for which I am searching. I think it was done in the late 1990's or early 2000's. In the first scene a truck on a country/road in a Latin American country comes to a border checkpoint. The border agent takes a picture of one of the passengers, who unbeknownst to him is a revolutionary leader.

Later, the border agent works for this country's police force and is hunting for this revolutionary. The agent has a daughter who takes dance lessons from the revolutionary leader's girlfriend. The agent falls in love with her not knowing her ties to the man he is hunting. Eventually the revolutionary is tacked down through his trash by a medicine he is using for a skin condition.

Answer (score 7):

The movie is **[The Dancer Upstairs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118926/)**

Storyline from IMDb, added after comment from TylerShads

> The story of Detective Agustin Rejas, a man clinging to the hope of an impossible love in an impossible world. Tracking Ezequiel, a delusional anarchist who incites the downtrodden masses to join in his brutal revolution against the fascist government in their unnamed Latin American country, Rejas finds solace in his sense of self-respect and the joy that his daughter and wife bring him. Then he meets Yolanda--his daughter's soulfully beautiful ballet teacher--a woman who sparks his long-forgotten passions and represents all that is good and all that is corrupt in their troubled country. But she, who appears to be a shelter from the storm, may in actuality be the storm's eye. Ultimately, as the revolution intensifies and the net closes around hunter and hunted alike, the dancer's truth will prove as elusive as the revolutionary's cause and the detective's peace

The Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dancer_Upstairs_%28film%29) for the movie, has the historical basis for the movie:

> The story is inspired by the Maoist insurgency in Peru known as the Shining Path. Its leader Abimael Guzmán, who was known by the nom de guerre President Gonzalo, was captured in an apartment above a ballet studio in the capital Lima in 1992. The ballet teacher Yolanda was based on Maritza Garrido Lecca, the woman in whose apartment Guzmán was found. Bardem's character was inspired by Benedicto Jimenez and General Antonio Ketin Vidal, the leading figures responsible for Guzmán's capture

Comment: Much better than my "Machete Kills" guess.  :P